# Google Fonts, CSS, Latin Question

Tags: html, css, character-encoding, latin, google-webfonts

I'm trying to use [this](http://code.google.com/webfonts/preview#font-family=Lato) font on my web.

It's in Lithuanian language, but it's not the point, the point is, that on google fonts previewer I can see characters beautifully, but on my site some specific symbols gets some nasty look.

[image: ScreenShoot]

Maybe anyone knows how can I solve this, I say, issue?

P.S. Or recommend me some other standard very light font which I could use ...

Comment: I have tested it, and I am not having that issue. Which character encoding are you using? Try using UTF-8, if you aren't already.

Comment: possible duplicate of [google webfont latin big chars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882109/google-webfont-latin-big-chars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those glyphs are not in the font. The standard fallback font of `serif` should be making it obvious; here’s what I see (using a pangram from Wikipedia):
[image: Screenshot]

If you download the font and look inside (using Font Book on Mac, or something like FontForge), you can see which glyphs are present or absent. To fix this, I would enter the characters you need into the previewer.

A quick selection of sans-serif fonts which contain the glyphs you need:

- [Museo Sans](http://www.josbuivenga.demon.nl/museosans.html) whose 500 weight may be used freely online.
- [Aller](http://www.daltonmaag.com/about/aller.html), which may require a license.
- DejaVu Sans and Droid Sans, which many users will have installed.
- Helvetica, Geneva, and FreeSans.
- Trebuchet MS, Verdana, Calibri, Candara, and Arial, which almost all users will have installed.

Calibri appears to be a decent match for Lato, so you might use `font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;` (without embedding anything at all).

Comment: Can you explain the fix part in more details ? :)

Comment: @Lukas I don't think there's any "fix" for this, since we're talking about those characters missing from the font file itself, so nothing short of adding those glyphs into the font file would.

Comment: @Yi Jiang, maybe you can recommend some other light font which will fulfil my needs ?

Comment: this is more an inelegant workaround than a solution to the problem. the proper fix is described in the other answer by M. Mussulis.

Comment: (although IIRC that solution was not implemented yet in 2010)

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem with 'Open Sans' font, and spent 3 hours trying to fix this, until I discovered the solution.

Try specifying the subset that matches the glyphs for your language, like in my case:

from this

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

to

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

See if that fixes your problem. Obviously make sure you check if the font used supports extra **subsets**. Don't forget they also support **Cyrillic** and **Cyrillic Extended**.

Cheers,
Michael.

Comment: Adding the subset solved the problem, thanks a lot! That should be the best answer.

Comment: I agree - this is the most accurate answer in my opinion, I wrote several service pages for baltic clients and this is the way I solved the issue