# google webfont latin big chars

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-webfonts, latin

i need help with google webfonts.
I am using Ubuntu Condensed, and all latin chars work fine on google webfonts website, but when i use it to my website, small letters **žšć** are big.
Using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed">
```

Here is example: http://dsgnet.net/desavanja/

At footer **Uslovi korišćenja** text is bad looking.

What is problem here, how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include additional subsets of the fonts.

Have a look under "2. Choose the character sets you want" here: http://www.google.com/webfonts/#QuickUsePlace:quickUse/Family:Ubuntu+Condensed

With all available subsets, your `<link>` would look like this:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed&subset=latin,cyrillic-ext,greek-ext,greek,latin-ext,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not enough to use only the latin-ext?

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Condensed&subset=latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```